# iPhone SDK: How to store the time each word was typed?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

My problem is twofold: 1) I'm trying to determine an eloquent way to allow the user to type into a UITextView and store the time each word was typed into an array. The time will be a float which starts at 0 when the user begins to type. 2) Conversely, I'd like the user to be able to tap on a word in the UITextView and display the time that word was typed (displaying in an NSLog() is fine). Considerations that may throw a wrench into a possible approach -- what if the user goes back to the top of the text and starts typing or to the middle of the text?

Even a suggested approach without code would be appreciated, because right now I'm drawing a blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to have a delegate for UITextView which implements [textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:).  In there you get every character that the user types.  You can get the time/date (using NSDate) and save it when the user starts a word.